# Isn't it bad to have a copy constructor making shallow copies?

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers

Let's consider that I have defined some classes `B` and `C`.

Now, let's consider the following class:

```cpp
class A{
public:
    int att1;
    int att2;
    std::shared_ptr<B> b_ptr;
    std::shared_ptr<C> c_ptr;
    A(const A& a);
};
```

Now, the question is about how to implement the copy constructor.

Currently in the code, this is what is being done:

```cpp
A::A(const A& a){
    att1 = a.att1;
    att2 = a.att2;
    b_ptr = a.b_ptr;
    c_ptr = a.c_ptr;
}
```

The last two lines will call the copy constructor of `std::shared_ptr` and increment the number of owners of the underlying pointer by 1.

But, isn't it a bad idea to have a copy constructor do that? It means that anywhere the copy constructor is called, it will actually have a relation with the initial object because the objects of class `B` and `C` aren't actually copied, but only the pointers are.

I realize that thanks to the use of `shared_ptr`, at least this will not be making any memory leaks.

Is it a common practice to do that? Is there any legitimate reason to do it? Or should I just avoid it all together?

Comment: `shared_ptr` is for shared ownership. So yes, you *are* meant to use them like that. If it's wrong, why does the class hold a `shared_ptr` to begin with?

Comment: Whether it is "bad" or not is a decision that must be made by you.  Both deep and shallow copying have their place, and it is your decision about the nature of what `A` is that determines whether a copy should just copy the pointer or also the pointed-to.

Comment: Nit: you should be using member initializer lists `A::A(...) : att1(a.att1), ... { }` instead of assignments. Note that `b_ptr = a.b_ptr` does not call the copy *constructor*, but the copy *assignment*. (To the call the copy constructor you need to use the initializer list... which is why you should use it.)

Comment: Re: "how to implement the copy constructor": in this case, there's nothing that needs to be done. The code in the question does exactly the same thing as the compiler-generated copy constructor, but somewhat less efficiently (because it doesn't use the member initializer list). So just leave it out. The compiler will do it for you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's imagine class A is class Person and class B is class car.

Is it OK that a copy of class Person points to the same original car? Yes

--- So just copying a pointer is OK.

Is it OK that when the last copy of Person is destroyed the car gets destroyed?  Yes

--- So just copying smart pointers is OK.

Is it OK that a copy of class Person will get its own copy of a car?   Yes

--- So copying the whole pointed to object is also OK.

All of those semantics can be valid. It is up to you to chose which one is appropriate for your logic.

Answer (score 1):

> The last two lines will call the copy constructor of `std::shared_ptr` and increment the number of owners of the underlying pointer by 1.

Actually, they call the copy assignment operator, not the copy constructor.

> But, isn't it a bad idea to have a copy constructor do that?

No, because `shared_ptr` is *meant* to be copied like this.  Sharing ownership of a pointer across multiple instances is its sole purpose.

> It means that anywhere the copy constructor is called, it will actually have a relation with the initial object because the objects of class `B` and `C` aren't actually copied, but only the pointers are.

Exactly, yes. That is what `shared_ptr` is specifically designed for.

> Is it a common practice to do that?

In this case, yes.  But if raw pointers had been used instead, then no.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question in your subject line, it is neither a good nor a bad thing for a copy constructor to make shallow copies.

There are use cases where deep copies (in the sense of copying creating a clone of all contained objects) are desirable and correct. There are other use cases where shallow copies (not cloning contained objects) are desirable and correct.     So it is up to you, as designer of your class, to decide what copying semantics are appropriate.

In your particular example, your class `A` contains a `std::shared_ptr<B>` and a `std::shared_ptr<C>`, and the purpose of `std::shared_ptr` is to provide shared ownership of a managed object's lifetime   i.e. copying (or copy assigning) a `std::shared_ptr<X>` means the copy shares responsibility for managing lifetime of the same `X` as the original `std::shared_ptr<X>`, rather than somehow cloning the managed `X` and creating a `shared_ptr<X>` that manages the clone.

The problem in your example is therefore not with the fact that copying an instance of `A` does not do a deep copy of the `B` and `C` that it manages.    Assuming you actually seek a deep copy, the problem lies with your choice to use `shared_ptr` - you have chosen the wrong tool (and then need to write code to do the deep copy).

Incidentally, your copy constructor

> ```
> A::A(const A& a){
>   att1 = a.att1;
>   att2 = a.att2;
>   b_ptr = a.b_ptr;
>   c_ptr = a.c_ptr;
> }
> ```

does not do a deep copy either.   It is also unnecessary since the compiler will generate one for you that has the same net effect as;

```
A::A(const A& a): att1(a.att1), att2(a.att2), b_ptr(a.b_ptr), c_ptr(a.c_ptr)
{}
```

This uses copy constructors of `std::shared_ptr<B>` and `std::shared_ptr<C>` so differs from your implementation that default-constructs `b_ptr` and `c_ptr` first, and then assigns them using `std::shared_ptr::operator=()`.